# Ubuntu OpenVpn to Tor

Tags: server, vpn, proxy, openvpn, tor

I have never posted on here before so i appologise if i have posted this is the wrong place or it has been asked before.

I have an OpenVpn server which also has Tor installed.

I am wondering, just for curiosity purposes is there any way to route all the traffic coming to the server through the VPN over Tor so it would look like this

Client ---> OpenVpn Server -----> Tor ------> internet.

I assume this is possible but im only just learning about ip routes so was looking for a bit of guidance.

If anyone could help that would be great. I've found a few similar things on other forums but im not sure they are achieving exactly what i want, and i don't understand the  routing commands enough to change it to suit my needs.

Many Thanks

David